# changepoint detection with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am developing a shiny app, in which I am uploading and reading multiple datafiles.
I want to detect the `changepoint` according to the `cpt.meanvar`. For that, I am using `changepoint` and `changepoint.np` packages.

I want to be able to extract a particular part of the plot (i.e dataset) which to be used for further analysis and processing in the shiny app. This part should be able to get detected and extracted by detecting the changepoints.

```
M2 <- data.frame(x,y)
```

Here is my attempt to detect the changepoint and plot them on the graph:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = M2[,1], y = (M2[,2]-min(M2[1,2])))
mcpt <- changepoint::cpt.meanvar(df1$y, method = "PELT")
plot(mcpt)
```

This generates just a normal plot, when in reality it has to be a scatterplot.

Here is how the plot looks like:
[image]

Question 1) How can do the same thing with `ggplot`or `plotly`?

Question 2) If I were to separate some specific part of this scatterplot and use that part for further analysis, how can I do that? For e.g. if I want the app to automatically detect and extract the datapoints of the middle flat surface, which is raised above from the 0 line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the change points indexes & attributes to create the plots:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x=1:200,y = c(rnorm(100,1,1),rnorm(100,-1,2)))
plot(y)
mcpt <- changepoint::cpt.meanvar(df1$y, method = "PELT")

# Get the index of change points:
mcpt.pts <- attributes(mcpt)$cpts 
mcpt.pts 

# Get the position of the change points:
df1$x[mcpt.pts]

# Get mean and variance of the different segments
mcpt.var<- attributes(mcpt)$param.est$var
mcpt.var
mcpt.mean<- attributes(mcpt)$param.est$mean
mcpt.mean


# Plot with ggplot :
df1$mean <- rep(mcpt.mean,c(mcpt.pts[1],diff(mcpt.pts)))
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df1)+geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_line(aes(x=x,y=mean),color='red')
```

[image]

If you want to automatically plot each section between changepoints:

```
for (i in 1:length(mcpt.pts)) {
  if (i==1) {
      startidx <- 1 } else {
      startidx <-mcpt.pts[i-1]  
      }
  stopidx <- mcpt.pts[i]
  p <- ggplot(df1[startidx:stopidx,])+geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_line(aes(x=x,y=mean),color='red')
  print(p)
  readline(prompt="Press [enter] to continue")
}
```

Comment: I could not completely understand your answer, could you please elaborate a little bit.

Comment: As you didn't supply your data, see my edit for an example

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was helpful. Now, concerning my 2nd question. How can I extract a particular part of the scatterplot data? for eg. in your scatterplot, there are two red horizontal lines and one vertical line. If I want to extract the scatter points only related to the first horizontal line. If I am not interested in other scatterpoints, which are laying outside that zone . How can I extract that?

Comment: `mcpt.pts` gives you the change points indexes : 100, 200. So the first section is located between indexes 1-100, and the second one between indexes 101-200. Data for first section is : `df1[1:100,]`, just use this instead of `df1` in the `ggplot` call.

Comment: I get it, but in this case, you know where was the changepoints, that's why you could give the start and endpoint of the required dataset, in this form df1[1:100]. But what if the index of the changepoint changes with every plot. Is it possible?

Comment: See my edit : I added an example of a simple for-loop to plot each section between change points automatically